# Method errors "method insertn in class TestSwitch cannot be applied to given types"

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, case, statements

Here's my new problem, I can't seem to link **insertn()** and **updaten()** to **public static void insertn()** and **updaten()** due to the values I've given at **insertn(cID, dName, ePrice);** and same in **updaten**, how am I suppose to link them, I forgot how to assign the values **cID**, **dName** and **ePrice** to **ID**, **Product** and **Price** from the **database**, I've tried fixing this for the last 2 days and I don't want to waste anymore time as much as I did when I had that little problem before. Sorry if my english is bad. Please Help!

```js
package hardware.store;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestSwitch {
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("Select one of the following:");
        System.out.println("1) Select");
        System.out.println("2) Insert");
        System.out.println("3) Update");
        
        Scanner scanp = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int user = scanp.nextInt();
        
        switch(user){
            case 1:
                
                selectn();
                
                break;
            case 2:
                
                System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
                int cID = scanp.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Product Name: ");
                String dName = scanp.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Price: ");
                int ePrice = scanp.nextInt();
                insertn(cID, dName, ePrice);
                
                break;
            case 3:
                
                System.out.println("Update which ID: ");
                int hID = scanp.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Update Name: ");
                String iName = scanp.next();
                System.out.println("Update Price: ");
                int jPrice = scanp.nextInt();
                updaten(hID, iName, jPrice);
                
                break;
            default:
                
                System.out.println("Please choose from the given choice!");
                
                break;
        }
    }
    public static void selectn(){
        try{   
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");    
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=Workshop; user=sa; password=1234;");  
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet Res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Shop");  
            while(Res.next()){  
            System.out.println("Product ID: " + Res.getInt("ID"));
            System.out.println("Product Name: " + Res.getString("Product"));
            System.out.println("Product Price: " + Res.getFloat("Price")); 
            
            }
           }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }   
    }
    public static void insertn(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");    
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=Workshop; user=sa; password=1234;");  
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into Shop"
                       + "(ID, Product, Price)"
                       + "values ('', '', '')";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Insert Complete");
           }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
}
    public static void updaten(){
        try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");    
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=Workshop; user=sa; password=1234;");  
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet Res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Shop");  
            while(Res.next()){  
            System.out.println("Product ID: " + Res.getInt("ID"));
            System.out.println("Product Name: " + Res.getString("Product"));
            System.out.println("Product Price: " + Res.getFloat("Price")); 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you've singled out "try blocks inside switch" as the title... Have you done any debugging (either with a debugger or println) to find out at what point the program "hangs" ?

Comment: Not sure if this is your error, or the only error, but you are missing a { after while(Res.next()) in case 3.

Comment: As @HerbWolfe pointed out, there is a syntax issue. As it stands your code won't compile also. Anyways assuming that it's a mistake while you were posting your question, put some debug points and track the execution of the program. e.g., in case of 1, the insert block should get executed. Put a println at the beginning of that block. Then see if `Insert Complete` is getting printed or not. If not then you have issues with db connection/operation.

Comment: @Sudhansu Choudhary I'm a studying programmer and I don't really remember the rules of each codes, please show me the corrected version of my program, I'm sorry if this is too much to ask but I don't really know what to do and I've been stuck trying to figure this part in the last 3 days. I forgot to mention that I added a sqljdbc4.1.jar in my library in order to establish connection with the database, I've tested connecting to my db and fetching the columns which I created in my SQL and it worked so there are no issues with my db connections, this is a school project and i have 2 days left.

Comment: @Herb Wolfe I've tried putting curly braces after the while(Res.next())[which is this, While(Res.next){......}], it was helpful but nothing happened, still the same infinite "Running" at the bottom right corner.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I've tried putting "System.out.println(Insert...etc...)" before the insert block in my case 1 and it gives me this error "Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String".

Comment: @John3136 Is it misleading? I'm sry I don't know what to think when I came up with the title, I was about to put Help! in it but it doesn't allow me, and considering that I've been frustrated for days I didn't have that much of an idea, I've tried doing everything that I know of and nothing solved my problem, and nope haven't tried doing that. Help!!

Comment: @NoobProgrammer So your code has try blocks inside switch statements. What makes you think that is the problem? You could just as well have title it "Code that has variable s". A more correct title would be "Java code hangs" i.e. something that actually describes the problem.

Comment: @John3136 Yes I know it was dumb but I'm in a desperate need of help, and I'm a new programmer I just wanted to submit this project before 10th of December.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer When you say that netbeans just reads running in the bottom corner, is this before or after you enter your choice?

Comment: @HerbWolfe since before I posted this problem and until now, and this happens after I execute/run the program then it gives me this infinite "Running", so basically it loads infinitely before it even shows me anything so I don't even get to choose anything because it loads infinitely. I tried exiting and reopening my Netbeans and I even tried restarting/shutting down my pc and still the same result. Please I need help asap I'm going to submit this tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with netbeans, but it sounds like it's waiting for you to enter a number. What happens when you run the program from the command prompt?

Comment: @HerbWolfe Well it gave me this "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at hardware.store.HardwareStore.main(HardwareStore.java:13)" after running it in CMD, what does it mean?

Comment: When you get an error message, you should try to figure it out from the context of the message and what is going on in that section of code. Do a web search for the error message if you have to. In this case, it looks like you aren't entering an int.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Sorry for not replying, the project submission was eventually extended due to only 1 out of 31 students passed the project who did it correctly and will be submitted on 21st of Dec, I have a new problem. So I had a friend who helped me with my program and he did, only that he gave me hints and refers because he doesn't want me to cheat but only to help me a bit, so the problem is here.

Comment: You guys are probably annoyed by now but please I need this annoying project fixed because I have a even bigger project which is a group project and it's "Creating ATM application or simulator with Swing app or Web app".